# Unable to setup PPTP VPN on SUSE Enterprise 11

Tags: linux, vpn, pptp, opensuse, sles

I am new to Linux, however I will try to convey my question the best I can.

Right now we are using Windows Server 2003 as a DHCP server. It also has PPTP VPN installed. Users can get to VPN outside of the office just fine.

The public IP address of the VPN server (a separate VPN server is used which connects to Windows server) is 107.1.94.110

We are trying to migrate to SUSE Enterprise 11. Here are the settings files:

### **pptpd.conf**

```
localip 10.89.64.1
remoteip 10.89.64.100-150
```

The local IP address of the Default Gateway is 192.168.1.254 - I'm not sure if I need to put that into my local IP. I chose the 10. subnet to avoid ip confusion.

### **options.pptp**

```
#
#Lock the port
#
#
# We don't need the tunnel server to authenticate itself
#
noauth;

#
# Turn off transmission protocols we know won't be used

refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
require-mschap-v2
require-mppe-128
ms-dns 66.119.143.2
ms-dns 66.119.143.3
ms-dns 151.164.11.201 
proxyarp
nodefaultroute
lock
nobsdcomp
noipx
mtu 1490
mru 1490
```

..and finally

### **chap-secrets**

```
# Secrets for authentication using CHAP
# client    server      secret      IP addresses

username    pptpd   password    *
```

I also tried to set it up through "network-connections" in Yast, but with no success.

Any hint will be appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: Hope this helps: http://www.ardoros.com/2008/08/how-to-build-up-pptpd-vpn-server-on.html but honestly you should look at ditching pptp for something like an ssl VPN these days